# How to select from array in Rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a field `bidder` with arrays and objects like this(it can be also empty):

```
[
   [
      {
         "date":"08/17/1999"
      },
      {
         "time":"07:15:23"
      },
      {
         "increase":31.5
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "date":"04/01/1998"
      },
      {
         "time":"01:06:18"
      },
      {
         "increase":10.5
      }
   ]
]
```

How can I select first-array's `increase` value that means output should be 31.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript

```
r.table('test')('bidder').nth(0)('increase').run(conn, callback)
```

In Python and Ruby

```
r.table('test')['bidder'][0]['increase'].run(conn)
```

Edit: Queries for all documents
If you need to do more complex things that just returning a value, you can use the general "form" with `map`

```
r.table('test').map(function(doc) {
   return doc('bidder').nth(0)('increase')
}).run(conn, callback)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, It works when we use get(ID), how do we use without **get(ID)** ?  I have many rows that need to filter like this way.

Comment: There is one problem in **map** if the field is missing that is `bidder` does not content in some document. it will display error for all. Is there any easy way to escape from this?
here is the error:
**No attribute `bidder` in object:**

Comment: You can add a `.withFields('bidder')` before the map.

Comment: Thanks, it's works. just last question, How to display empty if `bidder` don't exists in a document. that means if there is bidder it will display value else it display null/empty. it would be great :-)

Comment: If you want `null` instead of "skipping" the document, you can add `.default(null)` inside the map `return doc('bidder').nth(0)('increase').default(null)`